# Advice on password vault software

Tags: passwords, password-management

Do you have any recommendation on any password manager, which is used primarily as a **vault**? I don't need any browser extension, any special functions, just a regular vault with ability to structure passwords in folders and the ability to create multiple accounts with specific permissions to read specific passwords/password folders.

Until now we've been using a password protected Excel file hosted on DropBox and it suits our needs perfectly, but the amount of conflicted copies and not being able to stop some team members from seeing specific passwords forced us for an update.

I've tried Passwork, this looked absolutely perfect, exactly what we need, they have a browser interface and even a mobile app, it is a well structured vault. However, I am not able to verify my account using our e-mails, because as their support said "we are somehow in their blacklist", not to mention I was waiting for their support to answer for more than a week.

Then I've tried Myki, it looks good, but it is more of a real-time manager than a vault. Also, it is primarily a mobile app and every time I need to find some password in my vault I have to authorize my desktop device using my phone. Incredibly annoying.

Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Hey, I don't want to see this closed, it would be good if you reworded this to not be specific product requests. Those are off-topic for this board and all of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using KeePass. But you wouldn't be able to create multiple accounts with different permissions there. You've mentioned a few online password management tools - I wouldn't trust any online tool to store all my passwords. If you need more then one person to have access and update the passwords database Keepass has a feature to synchronize with a file (in a network folder or in a cloud).

Answer (score 0):

I use a small TrueCrypt container. You can put anything there just like in any normal folder and you can mount it only when needed. If the system it is on stops by accident (reset, shutdown, etc) the data is safe since the container must be re-mounted in order to be accesses.

Comment: "The development of [TrueCrypt](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/) was ended in 5/2014 after Microsoft terminated support of Windows XP. Windows 8/7/Vista and later offer integrated support for encrypted disks and virtual disk images. Such integrated support is also available on other platforms (click here for more information). You should migrate any data encrypted by TrueCrypt to encrypted disks or virtual disk images supported on your platform." [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) is based on TrueCrypt  and still maintained.

Comment: TC still works on any Windows Server or W10 version. You should migrate anything. There is no actual need. VeraCrypt is overall good, but it is significantly slower than TC.

Comment: That's a strong opinion against the advice from TrueCrypt developers. "**WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure.** You should download TrueCrypt only if you are migrating data encrypted by TrueCrypt."

Comment: There is way more to the story and that warning is not put up by the original developers. Note that TC was never proven vulnerable from a security perspective. The rest is a bed time story.

Comment: E.g. the Open Crypto Audit Project's [TrueCrypt Cryptographic Review](https://opencryptoaudit.org/reports/TrueCrypt_Phase_II_NCC_OCAP_final.pdf) is indeed a good bed time story. The one active and verified [exploit](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/38403) for TrueCrypt 7 is not against its cryptographic parts, but is harmful enough in other ways.

Comment: I know that, but it's an OS bug and does not compromise access to an encrypted container. If we want to see truly bad implementations of encryption we can look at bitlocker. Here's an example of many: https://www.engadget.com/2018/11/06/microsofts-bitlocker-compromised-by-bad-ssd-encryption/ ;that is one of the reasons why the trustlevel is low in such solutions.